# offlineaduiocontext.resume() does not fire on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

offlineaudiocontext.state is suspended with page load on mobile safari. I used resume() method but that does not change the state and the state remains suspended. If i use a button click on the page, that changes the state from suspended to running.

```js
alert(offlineaudiocontext.state);
if (offlineaudiocontext.state === 'suspended') {
   alert('in if');
   offlineaudiocontext.resume().then(function() {
     alert('after resume' , offlineaudiocontext.state);
   });
}
alert(offlineaudiocontext.state);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe on mobile Safari, you MUST have some kind of user gesture to start an online AudioContext. Don't know why this requirement should affect an offline audio context.